# Using CSS in Java Fx 8

Tags: javafx

I want to use a .css file, but it doesn't work. 
The main code works, but the css file has no effect on "Button".
The main Code:

```
public class JavaFXDialog1 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        final Button button = new Button("test");
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(button);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 150, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //String path = "C:\\Users\\PackardBell\\workspace\\css\\src\\styles.css";
        //scene.getStylesheets().add((new File(path).toURI().toString()));
        scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///C:/Users/PackardBell/workspace/css/src/resources/style/StyleArcade.css");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

StyleArcade.css code:

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

the main class is in folder css
the .css file is in folder in /resources/style

Comment: Try `getClass().getResource("/resources/style/StyleArcade.css").toExternalForm()`

Comment: it causes : Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source).

Comment: i am working an windows with eclipse

Comment: What is the cause of the exception? `NullPointerException`? The issue is you have the wrong path to the CSS file. You probably need to post your project structure. At a minimum, you should not be using the src folder in that path (as it most likely won't be available at runtime...).

Comment: u need the full text?

Comment: the Path :C:\Users\PackardBell\workspace\css\src\resources\style

Comment: Just the cause (i.e. what it says after "Caused by"). Post the project structure to your question. The path to the source code on its own is not particularly useful.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException. then Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, so that just says the css file is not in that location. Again, you need to edit your question to include the project structure. Also, make sure the css file is being deployed to the build directory (probably `bin`) by Eclipse.

Comment: One question: If i go on Eclipse to File->New->Other. and type css, then i got an empty list. maybe my eclipse setting are wrong?

Comment: That's irrelevant to this question. You just need to make sure the CSS file is being deployed and that you have the correct path relative to the classpath. Did you check the CSS is in the `bin` folder (or wherever it is your class files are generated)? What is the structure of the `bin` folder?

Comment: In bin there  is only JavaFXDialog1

Comment: So you need to make sure Eclipse knows to deploy the CSS file. Your `resources/style/StyleArcade.css` is *inside* the `src` folder, right? Assuming that, you probably need to go and check the settings under "Project" -> "Properties". Choose "Java Build Path" and then check "Source" and "Order and Export" and make sure those make sense.

Comment: sry for my late response and bc of you i could solve the problem. thank you